Selenium proxy python
I want to change the browser address for the displayed page. Do you see an error in the code?
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=116.202.102.255:8080')
service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://2ip.io/")
time.sleep(500)


If you want a code review, you need to post your code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com because code reviews are not appropriate questions on SO. Are you receiving an error or is the code not working in some way? What is your question?

Be aware that the code is only on-topic on Code Review if it works correctly.
